# Criar novo objeto sem sobreescrever o antigo em javascript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, construtor

Tenho um formulário com vários inputs, disponível em https://jsfiddle.net/elenderg/6hofsyzw/
O objetivo é que o usuário possa armazenar várias aeronaves, que possuem uma série de valores. De que forma posso armazenar esses dados de forma que ao adicionar uma nova aeronave, ela não sobreescreva o valor anteriormente cadastrado? Estou estudando orientação a objetos, mas ainda estou empacado nesse aspecto.

```html
<form>
     <p>Matrícula</br>
     <input type="text" name="" id="matricula" placeholder="GOL1234" maxlength="10"></input>
     </p>
     <p>Origem</br>
     <input type="text" name="" id="origem" placeholder="SBSP" maxlength="4"></input>
     </p>
     <p>Destino</br>
     <input type="text" name="" id="destino" placeholder="SBRJ" maxlength="4"></input>
     </p>
     <p>Nível</br>
     <input type="text" name="" id="nivel" placeholder="F145" maxlength="4"></input>
     </p>
     <p>Hora</br>
     <input type="text" name="" id="hora" placeholder="0843" maxlength="4"></input>
     </p></br>
     <button type="button" onclick="CriaAeronave()"><u>A</u>dicionar</button>
     <button type="button" onclick="ExibirAeronaves()"><u>E</u>xibir Aeronaves Adicionadas</button>
     <button type="button" onclick="ApagarAeronave()"><u>D</u>eletar Aeronave</button>
</form>
<p id="lista"></p>
```

```js
var matricula = document.getElementById('matricula').value.toUpperCase();
var origem = document.getElementById('origem').value.toUpperCase();
var destino = document.getElementById('matricula').value.toUpperCase();
var nivel = document.getElementById('nivel').value.toUpperCase();
var hora = document.getElementById('hora').value;

 function CriaAeronave(matricula, origem, destino, nivel, hora){
    this.matricula = matricula;
    this.origem = origem;
    this.destino = destino;
    this.nivel = nivel;
    this.hora = hora; 
}

aeronave = new CriaAeronave(matricula, origem, destino, nivel, hora);

function ExibirAeronaves(){
    var lista = document.getElementById('lista').innerText;
    lista = aeronave.matricula;
}

function ApagarAeromave(matricula){
    delete aeronave.matricula;
}
```

```css
form{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:70%;
}
input{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 70px;
}
p{
    margin-left: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:12px;
}
button{
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: É um caso de se refazer o código, que tem várias inconsistências.

Comment: Consegui resolver meu problema armazenando cada objeto em um vetor (array). Creio porém que exista uma forma melhor de fazer isso.

Comment: A propósito, poderia apontas as inconsistências?

Comment: Uma delas é que vc está pegando os valores dos inputs fora de uma função.

Comment: Sem falar que existem vários erros de Html, tipo vc fecha tag **br** e tag **input** que não precisam serem fechadas. Sem falar que acho que você está confundindo **Função** com **Classe**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei interessante sua pergunta e como disse que está estudando achei que valia deixar uma resposta. Seu código apresenta vários erros como já mencionado nos comentários. Não sei dizer bem ao certo se instanciar uma classe através de uma função como fez **`new CriaAeronave(...`** é o mais correto, pois, não achei nada a respeito disso e sinceramente nunca vi isto empregado na prática, tem este material se quiser saber mais sobre [funções](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es) e este outro sobre [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) que pode ser interessante dar uma olhada:

```js
// Descreve a classe
class CriaAeronave {
  constructor(matricula, origem, destino, nivel, hora) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
    this.origem = origem;
    this.destino = destino;
    this.nivel = nivel;
    this.hora = hora;
  }
}

// Variáveis para utlização
var lista = document.getElementById('lista');
var listaVisb = false;
var aero_naves = document.getElementById('aero_naves');
var _listas;
var msg = document.getElementById('msg');

// Função que gera a classe
function CriaAeronaves() {
  // Pega os valores dos campos
  var matricula = document.getElementById('matricula').value;
  var origem = document.getElementById('origem').value;
  var destino = document.getElementById('destino').value;
  var nivel = document.getElementById('nivel').value;
  var hora = document.getElementById('hora').value;
  
  //Instancia a classe 
  var aeronave = new CriaAeronave(matricula, origem, destino, nivel, hora);
  
  // O que vai ser retornando no Html
  var resultados = `<br> <em>Origem: ${aeronave.origem} - Destino: ${aeronave.destino}</em> <br>`;
  
   var b = document.createElement('b');
   b.innerHTML = resultados;
   lista.appendChild(b);
   
   let span = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
   if(span) span.style.display = 'none';
}

function ExibirAeronaves() {
  listaVisb = !listaVisb;
  if (listaVisb == true) lista.style.display = 'block';
  else lista.style.display = 'none';
}

function ApagarAeronave() {
  var qtdBs = document.getElementsByTagName('b').length;
  lista.lastElementChild.remove();
  if(qtdBs == 1) lista.innerHTML = '<span>Nenhuma aeronave!</span>';
}
```

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 70%;
}

input {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 70px;
}

p {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

button {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#lista {
  display: none;
}

b {
  font-size: 15px;
}

span {
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Matrícula<br>
    <input type="text" name="" id="matricula" placeholder="GOL1234" maxlength="10">
  </p>
  <p>Origem<br>
    <input type="text" name="" id="origem" placeholder="SBSP" maxlength="4">
  </p>
  <p>Destino<br>
    <input type="text" name="" id="destino" placeholder="SBRJ" maxlength="4">
  </p>
  <p>Nível<br>
    <input type="text" name="" id="nivel" placeholder="F145" maxlength="4">
  </p>
  <p>Hora<br>
    <input type="text" name="" id="hora" placeholder="0843" maxlength="4">
  </p><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="CriaAeronaves()"><u>A</u>dicionar</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="ExibirAeronaves()"><u>E</u>xibir Aeronaves Adicionadas</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="ApagarAeronave()"><u>D</u>eletar Aeronaves</button>
</form>
<p id="lista"></p>
```

Comment: Mas você pode utilizar `new` para gerar instâncias através de funções, essa era a maneira de se criar instâncias antes do ES06.

Comment: Realmente , me expressei mal, poder pode, é que é uma prática que não vejo mais tão facilmente que exagerei. Vou editar a resposta, obrigado.

Comment: Por gentileza pode enviar algum link com material que aborda este tema de instanciar uma função? Acho que nunca vi isso na prática e não consigo encontrar nada a respeito.

Comment: Realmente me parece que especificações sobre isso desapareceram agora que a sintaxe para classe existe, eu consegui encontrar alguns links em inglês, principalmente respostas antigas do SO. [Aqui](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/javascript/new-keyword-in-javascript) tem um artigo sobre isso.

Comment: Opa valeu pelo link man!